# MailGun give me error code 400

Tags: android, android-volley, mailgun

I wanna send an eamil using mailGun and volley
this is my code:

```
ap params = new HashMap();
            params.put("from","Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox3f4c3762bc4c4e528f114c47f02417b5.mailgun.org>");
            params.put("to",toEtxt.getText().toString());
            params.put("subject",subjectEtxt.getText().toString());
            params.put("text",msgEtxt.getText().toString());

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String credentials = "api:"+EndPoints.privateKey;
            String auth = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);

            presenter.firePostRequest(params, headers, EndPoints.MailGunBase+EndPoints.MailApi);
```

and then I fire a request using volley

```
    public void PostRequest(final Map params, final Map headers, String url){
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response",response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("error",error+"");
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return headers;
        }


    };

    VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request.setShouldCache(false));
}
```

can anyOne say what's my wrong ?
I don't know where I did it wrong,Thanks

this is my error:

> "message": "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings."

Comment: 400 error code is for `Bad Request - Often missing a required parameter`.

Comment: @Kunu yes, exactly, but I dunno what's that missing parameter!

Comment: For that someone has to go through mailgun doc thoroughly.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/30722575/3022836](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30722575/3022836) Use this to post your volleyerror in logcat. It might help

Comment: Still nothing more than an error code 400

Comment: yes, found this error message:
                                                                "message": "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings."

Comment: Instead of this `"Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox3f4c3762bc4c4e528f114c47f02417b5.mailgun.org>"` you have to set up your own domain and address in their setting. GO through their documentation step by step.

Comment: Thanks man! you save my life:)